# Populate Wicket table with Ajax

Tags: ajax, wicket, wicket-6, wicket-1.6

Is it possible to have 1 input text field that accepts characters from the user, and as the user types, queries to a webservice are launched, and to update the contents of another component dynamicaly with the results of the webservice (which would be a table below the input text)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you prefer to use Wicket form controls and Data Table component then you need to make the call to the REST service in your impl of IDataProvider.

Otherwise, as I explained to you earlier today in your other SO post you can do this directly in JS without Wicket. It is a matter of taste and skills.

Comment: Thank you! :) You mean that if I want to use Wicket to load the data from a webservice hosted on 3rd party domain, I would need to pass throught my backend instead of consuming the 3rd party webservice directly, right?

Comment: That's correct! Wicket app will act like a proxy in this case.